# z3py: Symmetry breaking constraint by lexicographic order

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I have two arrays of integer variables (they represent 2D spatial coordinates) and one is a symmetric disposition of the other. To break simmetry I want to check that the found solution described by the first array (let's call it P) is in lexicographic order with respect to the symmetric solution (so I can discard the symmetric solution).
Anyway, I'm having trouble writing this a function that checks the lexicographic order:

So far (but it is incorrect), I came up with this:

```
from z3 import *
from math import ceil

width = 8
blocks = 4
x = [3, 3, 5, 5]
y = [3, 5, 3, 5]

# [blocks x 2] list of integer variables
P = [[Int("x_%s" % (i + 1)), Int("y_%s" % (i + 1))]
     for i in range(blocks)]

# value/ domain constraint
values = [And(0 <= P[i][0], P[i][0] + x[i] <= width, 0 <= P[i][1])  # , P[i][1] + y[i] <= height)
          for i in range(blocks)]

# no overlap constraint
no_overlap = [Or(i == j,  # indices must be different
                 Or(P[j][0] + x[j] <= P[i][0],  # left
                    P[j][0] >= P[i][0] + x[i],  # right
                    P[j][1] + y[j] <= P[i][1],  # down
                    P[j][1] >= P[i][1] + y[i]  # up
                    ))
              for j in range(blocks) for i in range(blocks)]


# Return maximum of a vector; error if empty
def symMax(vs):
    maximum = vs[0]
    for value in vs[1:]:
        maximum = If(value > maximum, value, maximum)
    return maximum


obj = symMax([P[i][1] + y[i] for i in range(blocks)])


def symmetric(on_x, on_y):
    if on_x and on_y:
        return [[width - P[block][0] - x[block], obj - P[block][1] - y[block]] for block in range(blocks)]
    elif on_x:
        return [[width - P[block][0] - x[block], P[block][1]] for block in range(blocks)]
    elif on_y:
        return [[P[block][0], obj - P[block][1] - y[block]] for block in range(blocks)]

#function I want to emulate
def lexicographic_order(a1, a2):
    for a, b in zip(a1, a2):
        if a < b:
            return True
        if a > b:
            return False
    return True

# my attempt: raise error "Z3 AST expected"
def lexSymb(a1, a2):
    for a, b in zip(a1, a2):
        tmp = If(a < b, True, False)
    if tmp.eq(True):
        return True
    tmp = If(a > b, False, True)
    if tmp.eq(False):
        return False
return True

lex_x = lexSymb1(P, symmetric(True, False))
lex_y = lexSymb1(P, symmetric(False, True))
lex_xy = lexSymb1(P, symmetric(True, True))

board_problem = values + no_overlap + lex_x + lex_y + lex_xy

o = Optimize()
o.add(board_problem)
o.minimize(obj)

if o.check() == sat:
    print("Solved")

elif o.check() == unsat:
    print("The problem is unsatisfiable")
else:
    print("Unexpected behaviour")
```

Let me know if it's possible to modify "lexicographic_order()" in such way that works with Symbolic expressions, or if there's another way around I've not seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to have a symbolic version of:

```py
def lexicographic_order(a1, a2):
    for a, b in zip(a1, a2):
        if a < b:
            return True
        if a > b:
            return False
    return True
```

I don't think this is what you wanted. Why? Note that in Python, `return` immediately exits the function. So, this will merely compare the very first elements of these lists (assuming they are non-empty), and return immediately. I don't think this is what you intended.

A lexicographic ordering usually means you have to compare the whole list.  This is how you'd code that symbolically:

```py
# Does a1 come before a2 lexicographically?
# We assume a1 != a2. If same, the algorithm will produce True.
def precedes(a1, a2):
    if not a1:
        return True
    if not a2:
        return False
    return Or(a1[0] < a2[0], And(a1[0] == a2[0], precedes(a1[1:], a2[1:])))
```

It's instructive to look at how this function works. First on a concrete value:

```py
> print(precedes([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
Or(True,
   And(False,
       Or(True, And(False, Or(True, And(False, True))))))
```

Note we *build* the AST that "computes" if the first list is lexicographically before the second. The above expression reduces to `True` as you can easily verify yourself, but we don't *compute* `True`, we build the expression whose value will be `True`. The importance of this construction becomes obvious when we run it on symbolic values:

```py
> print(precedes([Int('a'), Int('b')], [Int('c'), Int('d')]))
Or(a < c, And(a == c, Or(b < d, And(b == d, True))))
```

Now you see how the value is "symbolically" computed and does what you want it to do: It will evaluate to `True` exactly when the first list lexicographically-precedes the second. And when you **assert** this as a fact to the solver, it'll force that constraint on the model.

Hope that gets you going. You need to think in terms of "building" symbolic expressions, and thus Python's internal `if-then-else` is not something you can use, since it does not work correctly with symbolic values.

Comment: I'll try to set my mind in that way, thank you!